# Strange topology for the natural numbers.

Tags: general-topology

For every pair of positive integers $(a,b)$, let $S(a,b)=\{an+b\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}\cap \mathbb{N}$.
Prove that $\mathcal{B}=\{S(a,b)\mid a \text{ and } b \text{ are relatively prime}\}$ is a basis for some topology for $\mathbb{N}$.

Clearly, given $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $k\in S(1,k)$ taking $n=0$.

I don't know if this argument is correct and I don't know how to prove that given $S(a,b)$, $S(c,d)$ and $p\in S(a,b)\cap S(c,d)$, there exists $W\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $p\in W\subset S(a,b)\cap S(c,d)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if $p \in S(a,b) \cap S(c,d)$, then $p+acn \in S(a,b) \cap S(c,d)$ for any positive integer $n$.

> Bigger hint: take $W=S(ac,p)$

Comment: If $p\in S(a,b)$, then $p=ak_1+b$ for some $k_1\in \mathbb{Z}$, and if $p\in S(c,d)$, then $p=ck_2+d$ for some $k_2\in \mathbb{Z}$. I can see that for any $x$, $S(a,x)\subset S(ac,x)$. I saw the new hint, i'll try that. Is the other argument okay?

Comment: $p\in W$ iff $p=ac\cdot k + p$. Taking $k=0$ we see that $p=ac\cdot 0+p$, so $p\in W$. However, I don't see why $W\subset S(a,c)$. $w\in W \implies w=ac\cdot k+p$, but why would $w=a\cdot \hat{k}+b$?